# starting container process caused "exec: \"/tmp/installer.sh\": permission denied"

Tags: docker, bazel, docker-in-docker

I have a base image (named `@release_docker//image`) and I'm trying to install some apt packages on it (alongside my built binary). Here is what it looks like:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/package_managers:download_pkgs.bzl", "download_pkgs")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/package_managers:install_pkgs.bzl", "install_pkgs")

download_pkgs(
    name = "downloaded-packages",
    image_tar = "@release_docker//image",
    packages = [
        "numactl",
        "pciutils",
        "python",
    ],
)

install_pkgs(
    name = "installed-packages",
    image_tar = "@release_docker//image",
    installables_tar = ":downloaded-packages.tar",
    output_image_name = "release_docker_with_packages"
)

cc_image(
    name = "my-image",
    base = ":installed-packages",
    binary = ":built-binary",
)
```

But inside the build docker (a docker image which the build command runs in), when I run `bazel build :my-image --action_env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.1.2:2375`, it errors:

```
+ DOCKER=/usr/bin/docker
+ [[ -z /usr/bin/docker ]]
+ TO_JSON_TOOL=bazel-out/host/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/docker/util/to_json
+ source external/io_bazel_rules_docker/docker/util/image_util.sh
++ bazel-out/host/bin/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/contrib/extract_image_id bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/release_docker/image/image.tar
+ image_id=b55375fc9c651e1eff0428490d01b4883de0fca62b5b18e8ede9f3d812b3fc10
+ /usr/bin/docker load -i bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/release_docker/image/image.tar
+++ pwd
+++ pwd
++ /usr/bin/docker run -d -v /opt/bazel-root-directory/...[path-to].../downloaded-packages.tar:/tmp/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/marzban/downloaded-packages.tar -v /opt/bazel-root-directory/...[path-to].../installed-packages.install:/tmp/installer.sh --privileged b55375fc9c651e1eff0428490d01b4883de0fca62b5b18e8ede9f3d812b3fc10 /tmp/installer.sh
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/tmp/installer.sh\": permission denied": unknown.
+ cid=ce62e444aefe1f32a20575750a6ee1cc9c2f79d46f2f60187a8bc23f87b5aa25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same issue and it took some time for me to find the actual cause.

As you conjectured, there is a bug in your version of `rules_docker` repo. The actual problem is the assumption that a local folder can be directly mounted into the target image. Obviously, the assumption fails in the case of DIND (Docker-In-Docker).

Fortunately, this bug has been already fixed as part of [install_pkgs uses named volumes to work with DIND](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/pull/1277). As the title suggests, the solution is to use a named volume instead of short `-v src:dst`.

**So, the solution is to upgrade to v0.13.0 or newer.**

```sh
 rules_docker$ git tag --contains 32f12766248bef88358fc1646a3e0a66efd0e502 | head -1
v0.13.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I was running into the exact same problems as you. If you change '"@release_docker//image"' to ""@release_docker//image:image.tar" it should work.

The rule requires a .tar file (which is the same format as a docker save imageName). I didn't look into the code behind the rule, but I'd assume the image also needs access to apt.

Here is a working example

BUILD FILE

```
load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/package_managers:download_pkgs.bzl",
    "download_pkgs",
)
load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/package_managers:install_pkgs.bzl",
    "install_pkgs",
)

install_pkgs(
    name = "postgresPythonImage",
    image_tar = "@py3_image_base//image:image.tar",
    installables_tar = ":postgresql_pkgs.tar",
    output_image_name = "postgres_python_base"
)

download_pkgs(
    name = "postgresql_pkgs",
    image_tar = "@ubuntu1604//image:image.tar",
    packages = [
        "postgresql"
    ],
)
```

WORKSPACE

```
http_archive(
    name = "layer_definitions",
    strip_prefix = "layer-definitions-ade30bae7cb1a8c1fed70e18040936fad75de8a3",
    urls = ["https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/layer-definitions/archive/ade30bae7cb1a8c1fed70e18040936fad75de8a3.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "af72a1a804934ba154c97c43429ec556eeaadac70336f614ac123b7f5a5db299"
)

load("@layer_definitions//layers/ubuntu1604/base:deps.bzl", ubuntu1604_base_deps = "deps")
ubuntu1604_base_deps()
```

Comment: Tanks for the answer. But, it didn't help, unfortunately.  
Seems it's a bug when running `install_pkgs` rule with a **remote docker daemon** (i.e. with DOCKER_HOST action_env); since it mounts the `installer.sh` file and assumes it should be available at host...